# Determine the time-stamp of the earliest point in each polygon overlaid with a point layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector

Currently, I have a vector layer with polygons in it and another layer with points. There is a column with an exact time stamp in the points layer; I would like to determine the time stamp for the *earliest* point in each polygon (note - some polygons might not have a point in it.) There are probably 20,000-25,000 polygons in this layer, so unfortunately I can't do this polygon-by-polygon. Once I've identified the earliest point, I'd then like to create a column in the polygon with its time stamp. Any intuition on how I can do this?

Comment: This is basic tabular statistics. You can join on the fly or intersect once, then SELECT min(datecol) with a GROUP BY of polygon ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just added another sentence toward the end of my question. From there, how could I then create a column in the polygon with the time stamp of the earliest point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by adding a `virtual field` to your Polygon layer:

`array_min(overlay_intersects('point_layer_name',timestamp_attribute_name))`

This will handle finding the minimum timestamp within each given polygon and setting it as an attribute for each polygon

Polygons with no points inside will have a NULL attribute

Applying it to a layer where I search the`Random points` minimum `Id` attribute value, assigned to an `earliest` field.

[image]

Points labels are their `Id`, Polygon label in red is the `earliest` field attribute

[image]

Changes to either layer are handled dynamically:

[image]